# Searching an array for a specific text and setting a flag

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Basically I'm looking in an 7-zip list function array which lists all the files in a zip folder as well as lines of useless text.

I want to compare the file names with a source file list that I have made earlier before it was zipped and then if 1 or more are missing from the zip for whatever reason then do not process the delete part of the program.

I thought the best way to do this is set a flag when it cannot find a filename in the 7-zip list array and then check that flag before ir processes the delete. However becuase of the lines of useless text that it also in the array, as soon as one doesnt match the filename is sets the flag to false which causes it to never process the delete even if all files are present in the array.

How can I get around this ?
I currently have this:

```
arcstore = ShellandWait(ArcProg, """l""" & " " & NewZipName)                        'Command line to list files in a zip folder in an array

            For a = 0 To UBound(records)

                FileName = records(a)
                FileName = FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)                    'taking out the directory path so just the filename is left
                For i = 0 To UBound(arcstore.ArcFiles)

                    Zippedfilename = (arcstore.ArcFiles(i))                                     'Output of 7-zip List function

                    If Not Zippedfilename.Contains(FileName) Then
                        DeleteErrorFlag = True
                        cw.labelMsg("FIle not in zip is " & FileName)
                    Else
                        ZipFileCount = ZipFileCount + 1

                    End If

                Next

            Next
```

With "`Filename`" being the source file name and "`zippedfilename`" being the output line from the 7-zip array.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You could save the missing files first in a list and then after all you could display the list and create a delete function which delete all files in the list. Already tried something like this out?

Comment: Thanks Marco that is a good idea, although i would like to have it not delete anything at all if there is even 1 file missing. So say there is 5 source files and only 4 in the zip file then do not delete anything. Whereas if all 5 are there and they match then delete the source files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `Boolean` array of the same size as the `records` array where initially every `Boolean` value is set to `False`.

For every file name in the `records` array you check if it does exist in `arcStore.ArcFiles`, if it exists you set the appropriate value in the `Boolean` array to `True`.

In the end you can delete the source files, only if every value in the `Boolean` array is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the 7-zip list function array for any files that are not contained in the source file list. I'm not quite sure of the variable names, but I'm assuming that `arcstore.ArcFiles` is your 7-zip list function array and `records` is your source file list:

```
Dim not_in_zip() As String = arcstore.ArcFiles.Where(Function(file) Not records.Contains(file))

If not_in_zip.Count > 0 Then
    'All of the values in "not_in_zip" are files not contained in the *.zip.
    'You can display all of the values by using String.Join(",", not_in_zip)
Else
    'Every file is contained in the *.zip
End If
```